# How to find the raw keycodes for xkb?

Tags: xorg, xkb

At first glance, it seems /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/ contains the mapping of *raw keycodes reported by the device*, and 'showkey --scancodes` command can return the *scancode*. It's easy to think that they are the same thing.

But they are evidently different.`showkeys -scancodes` reliably returns the Linux Keycode, as in [Linux Keycode Table](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/howlinuxworks/linux_hlkeycodes.html) converted to hex; while 'raw keycode' in xkb refer to are always different than the table.

Take the key <kbd>1</kbd> for example:

- `showkey --scancodes` returns `0x02` as the keycode of <kbd>1</kbd>
- in xorg, the symblic name is `<AE01>`, which has `10` as its raw keycode, certainly not `0x02`.

  ```
  $ grep AE01 /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev 
  <AE01> = 10;
  ```

So, for the purpose of configuring xkb, how to find the raw keycode for any key, given that `showkey --scancodes` is not suitable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `xev` program will output the expected keycodes. For your example of  <kbd>1</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x600001,
    root 0xd4, subw 0x0, time 6931965, (284,-10), root:(285,560),
    state 0x0, keycode 10 (keysym 0x31, 1), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (31) "1"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (31) "1"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x600001,
    root 0xd4, subw 0x0, time 6932164, (284,-10), root:(285,560),
    state 0x0, keycode 10 (keysym 0x31, 1), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (31) "1"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: It turns out that in X and in Linux console keycodes are treated very differently. In console, key stroke signals are translated to a Linux keycode map, which is not used in X at all. In X, these key strokes are read as-is in the form of keycode - which is not the Linux keycode map - and translated to keysyms. So whatever `showkey` outputs has nothing to do with X. That's where I got it wrong.